# WebClient.DownloadFile is not working with newtonsoft.dll version 13.0.1

Tags: c#, web-services, json.net, webclient

I am getting exception from below code with specifically version of 13.0.1 of "Newtonsoft.dll". However, if I downgrade newtonsoft.dll with the lower version I am not getting the error message.
My concern is 12.0.2 version of newtonsoft is vulnerable. (I am getting vulnerability exception from the CodeQL scan If I scan my application using 12.0.2 version of newtonsoft.dll)

Any Idea what should be resolution on this??

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(webResource, zipFilePath); //Getting error from this line
}
```

Exception message :-

```
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
```

Comment: Have you googled the error message? There is some info about it. However, you should probably just use HttpClient instead of WebClient.

Comment: @Crowcoder - Thank you for the response. I have googled that error but it was not useful for me. Majority of the answers I found is to resetiis & i did it. But this error is not getting solved.

Comment: I saw something about a hotfix if you are using .NET Core 2. Are you using such an old version of Core?

Comment: @Crowcoder - I am using traditional webapi services. We are not using dotnet core.

Answer (score 0):

There is no JSON deserialization involved or a hint of Newtonsoft's classes in the code snippet. How did you come to the conclusion that it is the cause?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Once you have enough rep you'll be able to post comments.

Comment: I would say because the stack trace has: "...at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)..."